# awk if same string then print in 1 line

Tags: awk

i have this log text file:

```
<ma x="1">ab</ma>
<ma x="2">af</ma>
<ma x="3">ji</ma>
        <r x="1">0</r>
        <r x="2">0</r>
        <r x="3">0</r>
```

and want to make output like this?

```
<ma x="1">ab</ma><r x="1">0</r>
<ma x="2">af</ma><r x="2">0</r>
<ma x="3">ji</ma><r x="3">0</r>
```

x is dynamically can be more than 3 counters. Anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^ +/,""){print a[++c] $0; next} {a[NR]=$0}' file
<ma x="1">ab</ma><r x="1">0</r>
<ma x="2">af</ma><r x="2">0</r>
<ma x="3">ji</ma><r x="3">0</r>
```

If the leading white space is actually a tab then replace `^ +` with `^\t+`. If it could be a mix of either then use `^[[:space:]]+` in a POSIX awk or `^[ \t]+` in any awk.

Comment: Beauty - after all these years I still often overthink stuff =} This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

With `rows` being the name of the file here....

```
awk '{m=gensub(/.+ (x="[^"]+).*/, "\\1", "1",$0);gsub(/^ +/,"",$0);a[m]=a[m] $0}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' rows
<ma x="1">ab</ma><r x="1">0</r>
<ma x="2">af</ma><r x="2">0</r>
<ma x="3">ji</ma><r x="3">0</r>
```

We find the variable definition x="????" and store that in `m`; we strip leading blanks; we assign the whole row to an array based on m; then we iterate over the array and print it.

Note: `gensub` is a non-posix extension specific to `GNU awk`.
And the `awk` hash-arrays aren't guaranteed to maintain order; the fact that the above copy & paste has the output in the right order is purely coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

```
lastline=$(wc -l < log) ; awk -v line=$lastline '{ if(NR<=line/2) arr[NR]=$0; gsub(/^ +/,"",$0); if(NR>line/2) print arr[NR-line/2] $0}' log
```

Considering `x` value increments in order with lines, I am only printing first half and second half of file side by side rather than storing and matching `x` values.

- `wc -l` is to get number of lines which in this case is `6` so file lines are splitted to `3 - 3` within `awk`